# How do i delete spaces in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column which is very likely to have 0 or 1 space in the middle of it. I would like to remove it. A1 is the column while these forumulas are in A2, A3

```
=UPPER(TRIM(A1))
=REPLACE(A2,FIND(" ",A2),1,"")
```

The problem is with find. I suspect it finds no space and errors. The below is my result.
How do I delete all spaces in a row? or delete at least one space in the middle of the row?

```
123456  123456  #VALUE!
123 456 123 456 123456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace any spaces in A2, which I think is what you want (your question talks about both "cell" and "row"):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the beginning "space" from an excel cell (after export data into an excel sheet) by the following:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160), " "))
```

Answer (score 0):

`a3 = right(a2,4)` or however many number from the right to the gap

`a4 = left(a2,2)` or however many numbers from the left to the gap

`a5 = a4&a3`

Copy result and paste as value where required.

Comment: Far messier than the original solution, plus if the numbers to the right or left vary per row then this solution would be more time consuming to implement than manually removing the spaces